# Merge ram and memory?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retag-request

[[ram](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ram)] has 277 questions; [[memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory)] has 296. Should we:

1. Merge the two into [[ram](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ram)]?
2. Merge the two into [[memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory)]?
3. Leave both of them alone?
4. Retag [[memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory)] questions that aren't about RAM into another tag, and retag [[ram](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ram)] into [[memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory)]?
5. Retag [[memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory)] questions that aren't about RAM into another tag, and retag the remaining [[memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory)] questions into [[ram](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ram)]?
6. Retag [[memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory)] questions that aren't about RAM into another tag, retag the remaining [[memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory)] questions into [[ram](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ram)], then retag the questions that were temporarily retagged back into [[memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory)]? (probably not)

Comment: So which one wins? This is why you fill out the rest of the question, to argue for one tag over the other, showing some counts even.

Comment: Can we please not have "title says it all" as the post content ?

Answer (score 3):

But let's not forget that we have non-RAM related memory questions! Like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/171196/need-help-in-analyzing-memory-dump) one for example. Maybe we should encourage users somehow to use RAM tag more and leave memory for more general questions?

Comment: I agree, and think there are some - however, that one shouldn't really be memory, but memory-dump or similar.... ... I think!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a bad request, but I am not sure which.

I think memory is more accurate but, many non techie people may get it confused with hard drive space where as RAM can only mean one thing.

There are arguments with both, but to prevent confusion, I think it should be RAM.